# mysql_num_rows error with omegle clone

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-num-rows

Upon downloading an omegle clone. This is of course poorly written, so there is an error in a crucial file. [here's the site](http://pasteit.comlu.com/) if you want to check it out. The error I get is `Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a1687121/public_html/listenToReceive.php on line 11` here is the file:

```
<?php
$userId=$_REQUEST["userId"];

$msg   ="";
$randomUserId;

include ('config.inc.php');
include ('database.inc.php');
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chats WHERE userId = $userId ");

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM msgs WHERE randomUserId = $userId ORDER BY sentdate limit 1");

    $id    =0;

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
        $id          = $row["id"];
        $msg         =$row["msg"];
        $randomUserId=$row["userId"];
        }

    if ($id != 0)
        {
        mysql_query ("DELETE FROM msgs WHERE id = $id ");
        mysql_query ("INSERT INTO oldMsgs(userId,randomUserId,msg) VALUES( $randomUserId,$userId,'$msg'); ");
        }
    }
else
    {
    echo "||--rut roh!--||";
    }

mysql_close ($con);

echo $msg;
?>
```

I checked it a million times. I cant find anything wrong. Thanks!

Comment: [As always](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+mysql_num_rows+valid+result+resource), check `mysql_error()` after the `mysql_query()` call.  If `$result` isn't a result resource, `mysql_error()` will tell you why.  Very possibly, your database connection isn't active.

Comment: Also, note that your query is vulnerable to SQL injection. You have not escaped `$_REQUEST['userId']` with `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: -1.  This comes up once an hour.  Google could have told you what this error was and how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chats WHERE userId = $userId ");
// add the error check
if (!$result) {
    die('ERROR: ' . mysql_error());
}
```